# sa25 vs sar25: What is the difference?

Tags: sar

I collect performance data like this:

```
# Activity reports every 10 minutes everyday
*/10 * * * * root [ -x /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 ] && exec /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S ALL 1 1

# Update reports every 6 hours
55 5,11,17,23 * * *     root [ -x /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 ] && exec /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

Two files get generated per day: `saDD` and `sarDD`

I tried to find the file type, but failed:

```
server:/var/log/sa # file 201906/sar26
201906/sar26: ASCII text

server:/var/log/sa # file 201906/sa26
201906/sa26: data
```

What are saXX and sarXX? What is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the **sa** files are specific data files that can only be read an interrogated using the **sar** package. If you want to extract and analyze data from **sa** files, use `sar -f [filename]`.

The **sar** files are just ASCII files that can be read with anything you want (cat for example), so **sar** files can be directly analyzed, they don't need anything extra.

Comment: In my cronjob (see question above) there is no `sar`. I guess `/usr/lib64/sa/sa2` is the equivalent.

Comment: /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 is used for daily reporting. Cron'ed,  it will generate a daily report called /var/log/sa/sardd (where dd is the day).

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for all over the internet. sa is the binary version of the output whereas sar is the human readable version of that